# 83B with for contribution of stock with a low basis in a 721 transaction with forfeiture

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, start-up, 83b-election

I have some stock in a small startup (that I work for) that as part of a 721 transaction is being "acquired" by an LLC.  Let's say my basis in the stock is $10 and I am to receive $1000 share of the LLC.

I am assured by everyone (multiple lawyers and accountants) that this would be a tax free transaction for me for now, EXCEPT 50% of the received LLC share is subject to forfeiture under various terms (25% each of the next 2 years) if certain targets aren't met or if I quit under certain circumstances.

I am getting lots of conflicting advice.  Some say it is hopeless and I will have to pay tax in each of the next two years on $247.50 (assuming it isn't forfeited).  Others are saying I should file an 83b election to "cancel out" the forfeiture provision and then the whole things will be tax free for now.

Even if filing the 83b is correct, what do I list as the amount paid for the $1000 of LLC, $1000 worth of old stock or $10 of old company stock?  Just getting so much conflicting info.

Thanks.